# How to keep text together

Tags: macros

I am currently creating various macros in order to format text.
Now I want to keep certain information together. It seems that
there are two ways in order to achieve this:

1. Use boxes such as `mbox`
2. Use a `~` to keep things together

Which method should be preferred?

Comment: In my experience, it's best to avoid telling TeX how to make its boxes.  I would use the tie.

Comment: "keep certain information together" can have wide interpretation.  Do you mean on a single line?  On a single page?  On the left side of the page? etc.  But I would say I'm a fan of boxes.  They are quite flexible in their placement, if that is a requirement.

Comment: In first instance I meant "keep things together on a single line". But it can be viewed broader as well (as in parbox).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your application.

1. If you use `\mbox`, hyphenation is prohibited and the inter-word spacing is fixed and might be different from the surrounding text. If you're using it for a single word, then there is no difference in the spacing, but using multiple words, then there might be (may not be visible, but still).
2. If you use `~`, the inter-word spacing is unaltered and flexible, and words may break at hyphenation points, just not at the inter-word space.

Let's look at some examples (surely extreme, but still). Segments of the texts have been colour-coded to highlight any changes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Default paragraph:}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at ultrices 
quam, condimentum varius leo. Morbi dignissim ut felis id molestie. Pellentesque 
\textcolor{green}{convallis quam lacus, sit amet sodales mauris posuere nec}. Fusce \textcolor{red}{something} 
porttitor vehicula. Pellentesque maximus nunc fermentum eleifend fermentum. 
Phasellus dolor nisl, suscipit vitae leo a, iaculis sollicitudin diam. 

Curabitur a consectetur libero. Duis laoreet lacus turpis, ac 
\textcolor{blue}{pharetra justo venenatis} quis.

\bigskip

\noindent{\bfseries \verb|\mbox| paragraph:}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at ultrices 
quam, condimentum varius leo. Morbi dignissim ut felis id molestie. Pellentesque 
\mbox{\textcolor{green}{convallis quam lacus, sit amet sodales mauris posuere nec}}. Fusce \textcolor{red}{something} 
porttitor vehicula. Pellentesque maximus nunc fermentum eleifend fermentum. 
Phasellus dolor nisl, suscipit vitae leo a, iaculis sollicitudin diam. 

Curabitur a consectetur libero. Duis laoreet lacus turpis, ac 
\mbox{\textcolor{blue}{pharetra justo venenatis}} quis.

\bigskip

\noindent{\bfseries \verb|~| paragraph:}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at ultrices 
quam, condimentum varius leo. Morbi dignissim ut felis id molestie. Pellentesque 
\textcolor{green}{convallis~quam~lacus,~sit~amet~sodales~mauris~posuere~nec}. Fusce \textcolor{red}{something} 
porttitor vehicula. Pellentesque maximus nunc fermentum eleifend fermentum. 
Phasellus dolor nisl, suscipit vitae leo a, iaculis sollicitudin diam. 

Curabitur a consectetur libero. Duis laoreet lacus turpis, ac 
\textcolor{blue}{pharetra~justo~venenatis} quis.

\end{document}
```

`something` (red) is unbroken (not hyphenated) in the case of the default and `~` paragraph, as the line-breaking algorithm felt it was optimal to do so. However, in the `\mbox` paragraph, the spacing of `convallis ... nec` (green) altered the paragraph layout, making it "more optimal" to break `some-thing`. The inter-word spacing couldn't be expanded to make `something` roll over to the next line. Also, it couldn't be shrunk enough (if that was a possibility) to make it fit on the same line.

`pharetra ... venenatis` (blue) was allowed to break mid-word when using `~`, but `\mbox` strictly avoided this. In both cases you may run into the problem of an overfull (or underfull) line, as you're prohibiting some form of natural breaking. That's what happened in the example, as the `\mbox` paragraph could spread out the inter-word space wide enough to make `pharetra ... venenatis` roll to the next line. For the `~` paragraph, the only optimal breaking point was `ve-nenatis`, but that still overflowed into the margin.

Answer (score 5):

i'd say, it depends.

i use `~` quite often to guide line breaking in multi-line titles and headings, and for references like `fig.~1` (where it also yields a regular interword space rather than an end-of-sentence one). but it doesn't prevent hyphenation of the words, and it doesn't prevent space-stretching or shrinking.

if i have a phrase where hyphenation must be prevented, and "default" spacing is important, then a box is the thing.